# Concat query result with equals values into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

I have the following query result:

| Id | FKId | Count1 | Count2 | CountAll | Name | OriginalName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 1 | 0 | 1 | Food | Some value |
| 1 | 101 | 0 | 1 | 1 | Drink | Some value |
| 1 | 102 | 1 | 0 | 1 | Drink | Some value |

What I want to do is to return all the FKId with same Name value into one row, something like this:

| Id | FKId | Count1 | Count2 | CountAll | Name | OriginalName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 1 | 0 | 1 | Food | Some value |
| 1 | 101, 102 | 1 | 1 | 2 | Drink | Some value |

At the moment this is the query that returns the 3 rows:

```
SELECT 
    t1.Id, t2.FkId, 
    COUNT(some case when here) [Count1], 
    COUNT(some case when here) [Count2], 
    COUNT(t2.FkId) [CountAll], 
    t3.Name, t3.OriginalName
FROM
    table1 t1
JOIN 
    table2 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
JOIN 
    table3 t3 ON t2.FKId = t3.FkId
GROUP BY 
    t1.Id, td.FkId, t3.Name, t3.OriginalName
```

I tried adding this to my current query:

```
DECLARE @Ids VARCHAR(8000) 
(SELECT @Ids= COALESCE(@Ids+ ', ', '') + t2.FkId),
```

But I'm getting an error

> Incorrect syntax near '='

Answer (score 3):

You want to use STRING_AGG function.... something like

```
   SELECT STRING_AGG(t2.FkId, ', ') as ID_LIST
```

Here is the MS documentation on it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16